# Fine MongoDB integrated PHP Framework?

Tags: php

I am having a medium size project using CakePHP right now. It is/was using MySQL as database.

While after I heard and did some research on MongoDB. I would like to give it a try.

However, the way CakePHP implements model was designed for MySQL,even with the Mongo for PHP plugin. It's still using the 'inconvenient' way.

So, Is there a PHP framework that integrates MongoDB well and has the same(or almost the same) database APIs as MongoDB does.

Comment: MongoDB is NoSQL, so maybe you shouldn't insist on using a sql based syntax?

Comment: @winkbrace yeah, CakePHP's Model APIs are for SQL queries. So I was looking for a replacement that has the same API as MongoDB does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Laravel 4.x with jenseggers mongoDB package:
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

You can also give Yii a shot or Doctrine which should give you mongoDB support out of the box.

Ultimately out of personal experience I recommend Laravel due to its elegant way of communicating with the database; if done correctly, you don't need to write a single SQL query.

Comment: Thanks bro, Laravel seems to fit my taste,xD. It is elegant, like Django.